# Video player error playing local videos

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-videoview

I'm trying to create a activity with a Video Player.

The problem is that in some devices (ex. `Android 4.0.4`) when I try to play local video the `VideoView` shows LogCat error :

```
MediaPlayer(6757): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

And on screen:

```
"Cannot play video. Sorry, this video cannot be played"
```

The videos be recorded with `MediaRecorder` and this is the config of MediaRecorder

```
public boolean initRecorder(){
        myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        myRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            myRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));                        
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFilePath()); //videopath.mp4
        myRecorder.setVideoSize(size.width, size.height);       
        myRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mySurfaceHolder.getSurface());
        if(prepareRecorder()) return true; 
        else return false;          
    }
```

And played with VideoView like this:

```
VideoView vidDisplay = (VideoView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.vidDisplay);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(_imagePaths.get(position));
vidDisplay.setVideoURI(uri);
vidDisplay.setMediaController(new MediaController(_activity));
vidDisplay.requestFocus();
vidDisplay.start();
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is related to the user permissions of the video. Is there a way to create aguna videos with `MediaRecorder` with read permissions for everyone?

I tried to open the file and then make `setReadable(true)` but this not work

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: make sure that the video file have .mp4 extension

Comment: then try my solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117538/how-to-play-mp4-video-file/24117776#24117776

Comment: Hi, @kgandroid the file extension is mp4, checked. ;). I've tried your code and the problem persist. On the other hand if I try `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)` the thumbnail returns null. In the documentation says that this error ocurs when video file is corrupt or video format is not compatible. This is strange because i use mp4 format. Thanks

Comment: I've edited the original question. Any ideas?